# round datetime to nearest min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

how do I round below :

```
                   Time
0   2021-11-23 08:07:35
1   2021-11-09 23:12:13
```

to nearest min :

```
                   Time
0   2021-11-23 08:08:00
1   2021-11-09 23:12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce Time to datetime and use dt.round(Minute) to round. Code below

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.round("T")



 Time
0 2021-11-23 08:08:00
1 2021-11-09 23:12:00
```

Comment: looks good thanks ! may I know what does the "T" mean?

Comment: 'T' stands for Minute